# MySQL CPU at 400% when trying to drop a table

Tags: mysql

DROP TABLE table_name

and the CPU goes to 400% and it doesn't drop but the whole server is messed up.

any ideas?

MySQL db about 50MiB in size total. 11000 records in this table with no indexs apart from primary.

Comment: What SQL Server application? MySQL, MSSQL, other?  Is the table in use at the time?  Is the table massive?

Comment: ..are there any indices? PK/FK constraints? what OS? what kind of hardware?

Comment: Updated to represent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer was a corrupted index or some-such. I recreated the db then copied over the data and it worked.

Weird but I guess it is one of those things that happen.

Answer (score 0):

What does a:

```
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
```

display from the mysql client? I suspect that is will just show the drop statement, but it's somewhere to start.

Is there anything in dmesg or /var/log/messages, /var/log/mysql etc that suggest a greater problem? I am presuming it's a linux box - though you haven't mentioned what OS.